# How to check if a string contains a number in powershell

Tags: string, numbers, powershell-3.0, contains

How do I check if a string contains any numeric value.

Ex: paul123

The above example contains numeric value so I should get the output as true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a regular expression match:

```
'paul123' -match '\d'
```

`\d` matches a digit (0-9), so the expression will evaluate to true if the string contains at least one digit.